# Chosen: retrieve the UI container from the raw select DOM element

Tags: javascript, jquery, prototypejs, jquery-chosen, prototype-chosen

I use Harvest's Javascript library to enhance `<select>` elements.

https://github.com/harvesthq/chosen

This library creates a `<div>` element along with the original `<select>`. This `<div>` contains the Chosen enhanced UI:

```
<select multiple id="my-list" class="chosen">
    <option value="1">One</option>
    <option value="2">Two</option>
    <option value="3">Three</option>
    <option value="4">Four</option>
    <option value="5">Five</option>
</select>

<div class="chosen-container chosen-container-multi ..." id="my-list_chosen">
    <ul class="chosen-choices">
        <li class="search-choice">
            <span>Three</span>
            <a class="search-choice-close" data-option-array-index="2"></a>
        </li>
        <li class="search-choice">
            <span>Five</span>
            <a class="search-choice-close" data-option-array-index="4"></a>
        </li>
        ....
    </ul>
    ...
</div>
```

I would like to retrieve this Chosen UI container (the `<div>`), given that I only know the original `<select>` element. The challenge is that there may be more than 1 multiple select in the HTML document.

The easy case is when the `<select>` element has an ID, so the Chosen UI container has the same ID suffixed with `_chosen`, as you can see in the above snippet.

But Chosen does not require elements to have and ID attribute to work. So what about multiple `<select>` elements with no ID? What is the proper way to identify the Chosen UI container?

**[EDIT]** For those who wonder why I can't assume there is an "id" attribute on the `<select>`: I wrote a [small plugin to handle selection order for Chosen](https://github.com/tristanjahier/chosen-order), and I can't force users to put an ID on the `<select>` while Chosen does not require it itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally I've found a workaround. **There is no proper way to get the container provided by Chosen.**

**[Update]** : according to [this comment on Github](https://github.com/harvesthq/chosen/issues/2026#issuecomment-52581923), there is "officially" no proper way to get the Chosen UI element with PrototypeJS.

### With jQuery plugin

I've look into the CoffeeScript code of Chosen, and found something interesting. If you're using Chosen plugin for **jQuery**, the Chosen instance is stored locally thanks to **jQuery data() function**.

You can retrieve the Chosen UI container this way:

```
$(my_select).data("chosen").container[0]
```

### The general case

Unfortunately, with PrototypeJS plugin, there is no trick like that.

But we can make an hypothesis in the general case: **the Chosen UI container is the first next sibling of the raw `<select>` element.** This assumption is quite strong because, unless something moves the `<select>` or the Chosen container dynamically, this will always be true.

Here is a not so bad solution, using the 2 different frameworks:

#### Using PrototypeJS

```
my_select.next(".chosen-container.chosen-container-multi")
```

#### Using jQuery

```
$(my_select).next(".chosen-container.chosen-container-multi").get(0)
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not a perfect way to find what you are looking for but it will work most of the time, I would suggest putting an ID on the element or if you dont want to duplicate ids you can use the `.identify()` method that will put a unique id on the element, you just have to do if before you call Chosen.

---

If you can find the `<select>` with a CSS selector you can find the chosen container which is a sibling of that element like this

```
$$('select').first().next('.chosen-container');
//OR
$$('select.classname').first().next('.chosen-container');
//etc
```

This depends on the structure of the DOM, which is not a good way to do this normally but Chosen is pretty good about putting the rendered dropdown as a sibling of the target `<select>` Your mileage may vary

Comment: In fact I need it for a plugin I wrote, that is used by people I don't know. And I don't want to force them to have more constraints than Chosen has itself. Unfortunately, this is the solution I took on, for lack of an alternative. I found out a very good solution for jQuery though that I'm going to share as an answer soon.

Comment: IMO I think using `.identify()` would be a good solution - as it returns the id if its set - otherwise it puts a unique id on the element and returns that, which would "link up" the `<select>` and the rendered Chosen

Comment: My script is called only once Chosen has been applied, so I can't make this hypothesis. The hypothesis that the Chosen container is the next sibling of the raw `<select>` is much stronger IMO.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe not exactly what you're looking for, but the instance of chosen is supplied as second argument to the function handling `chosen:ready`. You could store the reference to `chzn.container` for later use. The important part is to attach the event handler before calling `.chosen()`, e.g.:

```
$(".chosen").on("chosen:ready", function (event, chzn){
    // "this" is the select element
    // "chzn" is the chosen instance
    let container = chzn.container;
    // ...
}).chosen();
```